# How can I copy file recursively ignoring destination directory structure?

Tags: linux, file-transfer

I have the following content on the source directory:

```
source/foo.txt
source/bar/another_file.txt
source/bar2/and_another.txt
```

I want copy those files to a destination directory which, after copy, shall look like this:

```
destination/foo.txt
destination/another_file.txt
destination/and_another.txt
```

How can I do this? It seems that "cp" lacks such an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` to find the files, and `cp` to copy them.

```
find source/ -type f -exec cp -t destination/ {} +
```