# CMD copy recursive, but squash directory structure

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer

Similar to [How can I copy file recursively ignoring destination directory structure?](https://superuser.com/questions/308015/how-can-i-copy-file-recursively-ignoring-destination-directory-structure) but in `cmd`.

I'd like to copy all files recursively, but in the destination folder I'd like to squash the directory structure.  I first looked at `xcopy`, but it does not allow the option to squash the structure (that I can see).

I then looked at `for`, but I cannot get it to work when there are spaces in the directory structure.  For example:

```
for /F %f in ('dir /b/s/A-D D:\Libs') do @copy "%f" D:\Bin /Y >NUL
```

This does not copy any files that reside in a path with spaces.  This seems to be due to the fact that `for` splits on spaces as well as carriage return characters.

If there is a solution that works in MSBuild, I would accept that too.

Comment: The 'answer' below is probably right but I'm too lazy to remember all the "tokens=*" parameters of the for command, so instead I'd run dir /b > filelist.txt in the folder containing the files you want copied, then run for /f %f in (filelist.txt) do copy /y %f c:\YourDestination. That does mean that any time there's a name conflict, the last one wins.

Comment: @MarkAllen you probably still need for /f "tokens=*" %f  or "delims=".  Otherwise if there's a space in any item in that file, then it just takes the first "token".  Doing "tokens=*" or "delims=" will make it behave sensibly!

Comment: @barlop True, or I could use do copy /y "%f" c:\YourDestination

Comment: @MarkAllen no, the question had that copy "%f", and it i think is probably needed, but wasn't enough to do the job, because the %f itself only had the part of the directories/paths before the space.

Comment: ^ barlop is correct.  %f in the copy command only contained the part of the path before the space. "nobody"'s answer below solved this - the %f now contains the full path

Comment: Oh wow you're right, sorry! :( I blame a lack of coffee.

Comment: `for /F` doesn't exist in DOS. [Windows cmd and DOS are completely different things](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: @phuclv I edited the question to specify CMD rather than DOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for /f "tokens=*" %f`

For more info: `for /?`

Comment: Which version of **DOS** introduced this syntax?